# Using $(this) inside a jQuery AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been all over Stack Overflow looking for a solution and none seem to work.

I cannot seem to figure out the issue. I have a button inside a `<td>` and on clicking it I want to make an AJAX call to update a database and upon success of that AJAX call I want to update the class of the `<td>` to mark the button as clicked.

I have tried `var that = this;` in the function. I've tried `context: this,` in the callback.

```
        function setScoreA(event,candidate,rubric,category,score){
            var author = document.getElementById("author").value;
            if(author != ""){
                    $.ajax({
                            context: this,
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "stressBoardUpdate.php",
                            data: "candidate="+candidate+"&category="+category+"&score="+score+"&author="+author,
                            success: function(){
                                    $(that).parent('td').siblings().removeClass('isScore');
                                    $(that).parent('td').addClass('isScore');
                            }
                    });
            }else{
                    alert("Author must contain something...");
            }
         }
```

Here is how the function would get invoked.

```
<input type="button" "="" value="5" onclick="setScoreA('Stress Board','Y235','Stress Board Rubric','Handled Stress','5');">
```

Comment: where is the `var that = this`? And how is this function called? Post the event handler for the click as well.

Comment: in a previous attempt :P  It used to be before `var author ...`

Comment: Also, why using native JavaScript for selecting by ID? The advantage of jQuery lies in how easy it is to select element. `$("#the-id")`.

Comment: You should be able to do it like that... `var that = $(this);` then in your ajax call: `that.parent('td')...`

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Are there errors in the console? What have you done to attempt to figure out what's happening?

Comment: no errors in firebug. i can get `alert()` to work but nothing with `$(this)`

Comment: im using `$(this)` because there are many buttons of the same class/type on the page and didnt want to give them all IDs

Comment: The issue here is you probably aren't calling `setScoreA()` in a way that sets the `this` value as you would like.  Please show us how `setScoreA()` is called.

Comment: Well `this` in your outer function is only correct if you've invoked that function properly. You haven't shown how that function is invoked!

Comment: I added one of the buttons that call the function

Comment: @h3rrmiller OK, well there's your problem. The way you've attached the event handler, `this` will not refer to the element involved in the event. Try `setScoreA.call(this, 'Stress Board','Y235','Stress Board Rubric','Handled Stress','5')` and then restore your "that" variable setup etc.

Comment: the reason I want to do this with `$(this)` is all of the buttons and their values are created dynamically with php

Answer (score 1):

`onclick="setScoreA` does not set `this` to the element clicked but rather to `window`.  The way you are using it.  The way you are using it, I'm not sure that you could actually get a reference to the element.  Instead of using `onclick`, you should bind an event listener (which you can do with jQuery anyway):

```
$("input").on("click", function () {
    setScoreA(this, 'Stress Board','Y235','Stress Board Rubric','Handled Stress','5');
});
function setScoreA(element, ...
    /* snip */
    context: element
```

If you *really* wanted to stick with `this` for some reason, you could use:

```
setScoreA.call(this, 'Stress Board' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make use `data` attributes in your code and setup a common [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) listener

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" class=".button-group" data-event="Stress Board" data-candidate="Y235" data-rubric="Stress Board Rubric" data-category="Handled Stress" data-score="5">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".button-group").click(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Also, I presume you are dynamically generating many buttons. The code above could be improved having only 1 click listener for the whole table, rather setting up a click listener for each item.

```
$("#wrapper").on("click", "input", function() {

    var event = $(this).data("event");
    var candidate = $(this).data("candidate");
    var rubric = $(this).data("rubric");
    var category = $(this).data("category");
    var score = $(this).data("score");

    setScoreA(this, event, candidate, rubric, category, score);

});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pYMRq/1/)**

**Resources:**

- [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)
- [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)